# Android : Parsing JSON file issues

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I've been fighting with some JSON parsing in my application and after 3 days of researching I still can't figure out the issue.

The error that is being sent is "org.json.JSONException: Value "

I got the error in a try/catch statement that I've been working on.

My Try/Catch looks like this :

```
Try {
    // Result comes in from an HTTP Request

    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject jObj = jarray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("results");
    String TeamName = jObj.getString("fulltext");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

The full JSON that I'm getting is located [here](http://bit.ly/197my8m), but the abridged version is as follows:

```
{
    "query-continue-offset": 50,
    "query": {
        "printrequests": [{
            "label": "",
            "typeid": "_wpg",
            "mode": 2,
            "format": false
        }],
        "results": {
            "Team:\"Die Unglaublichen\"": {
                "printouts": [],
                "fulltext": "Team:\"Die Unglaublichen\"",
                "fullurl": "http:\/\/wiki.planetkubb.com\/wiki\/Team:%22Die_Unglaublichen%22",
                "namespace": 822,
                "exists": true
            },
            "Team:(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks": {
                "printouts": [],
                "fulltext": "Team:(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks",
                "fullurl": "http:\/\/wiki.planetkubb.com\/wiki\/Team:(Can%27t_Stand)_Le_Kubb_Bricks",
                "namespace": 822,
                "exists": true
            },
            "Team:(OHC) Kubb Team": {
                "printouts": [],
                "fulltext": "Team:(OHC) Kubb Team",
                "fullurl": "http:\/\/wiki.planetkubb.com\/wiki\/Team:(OHC)_Kubb_Team",
                "namespace": 822,
                "exists": true
            },
            "Team:Andrewsons3": {
                "printouts": [],
                "fulltext": "Team:Andrewsons3",
                "fullurl": "http:\/\/wiki.planetkubb.com\/wiki\/Team:Andrewsons3",
                "namespace": 822,
                "exists": true
            }
        },
        "meta": {
            "hash": "46923025c2d5aac3ee963419db93485d",
            "count": 50,
            "offset": 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time even seeing JSON code and to be honest, it's a bit confusing at first but I can understand how the JSON works, just not how to get the data out of these arrays!

I'm missing something, I just can't see what yet...

Comment: the root is a JSONObject not a JSONArray

Comment: don't e.toString your exception. e.printStacktrace instead.

Comment: so instead of the jarray I should just have another object that contains the full JSON data?

Comment: this json is a little f**ed up(i think results should be an array) ... but ... pseudocode: `JSONObject res = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results"); foreach(String key in res.keys()){ String fulltext = res.getJSONObject(key).getString("fulltext"); }` ... [keys() is the key](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys())

Comment: you can paste json to some online viewer to see how it looks like try: http://bit.ly/123n8BQ (click on Viewer tab)

Comment: Selvin : much easier to look at and better than me trying to format it myself in Notepad++....

Comment: I have tried : `JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results"); TeamName = jobject.getString("fulltext");`
I know that's not quite right yet.  "results" is not an array but a bunch of objects and I guess I'm confused as to how I can get the list of "fulltext" values to put in a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is from this line:

```
String TeamName = jObj.getString("fulltext");
```

This is because the value `jObj` doesn't have a "fulltext" value. Instead, that field is a value of each child `JSONObject`. To avoid this error, you would first need to check if the `JSONObject` has the variable "fulltext":

```
String TeamName = null;
if (jObj.has("fulltext"))
    TeamName = jObj.getString("fulltext");
```

To simplify your JSON parsing, the [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) provides some simple ways to create `Map`s and arrays from `JSONObject`s and `JSONArray`s:

```
Map<String, ?> map = $.map(jObj);
for (Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String teamName = entry.key();
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) entry.value();
    Map<String, ?> team = $.map(json);
    String fulltext = (String) team.get("fulltext");//etc
}
```

Comment: I have tried using the droidQuery as suggested and using the sample code above does not work.  I get an error in Eclipse on the "for" line of : "can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" with "map" highlighted (after the :)

Comment: @Vidar see the edit. I forgot to include the `.entrySet()` call to allow you to iterate over the map.